# Updating a select menu using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I currently have a page with one select menu called `searchuniversity`. Once the user selects something from this select menu I simply read the select menus value and then using that value read from an array. This array has multiple values with in it and based on those values I wish to added these values to the select menu `searchuniversitycampus`. Now for some reason everything is read out of the arrays properly as I have debugged the code but for some reason the select menu doesn't have any options added to it. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#searchpage',
function()
{
    $('#searchuniversity').change(
    function() 
    {
        var IDSelected = $("#searchuniversity").val();
        var Arrayiterate = ArrayCampus[IDSelected];
        var SelectDropDown = document.getElementById("searchuniversitycampus");

        for (var i = 0; i < Arrayiterate.length; i++) 
        {
            var arrayofcampus = Arrayiterate[i];
            var CampusName = arrayofcampus[0];
            var CampusValue = arrayofcampus[1];
            var NewOption = new Option(CampusName,CampusValue);
            SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
            SelectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
        };
        $("#searchuniversitycampus").closest('div.ui-select').show();
    });

}
);
```

I'm not sure why the code isn't working. Further information on the searchuniversitycampus element is that it is hidden on the page. I then populate it with options and the show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have try to refresh the select element?

```
//refresh value         
$('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: Any particular reason it is just showing the first element in the list and not the rest of the list? After the refresh it shows the 1st element in the list but when I click on it it doesn't show the rest of the list

Comment: @user1638809 where do you put the refresh? Check if the refresh is after the for-loop...

Comment: yep the refresh is directly under the .show() line in the code above but for some reason no list appears

Comment: @user1638809 can you create a `jsfiddle`? Maybe you will have to create another question...

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, the following code worked: $('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu({'refresh': true}); The refresh needed the brackets for some reason